# Is it necessary to disable strict name checking in Microsoft SQL 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I want to connect to a new Microsoft SQL 2014 server using CNAME records. I have not yet followed any of the steps to disable strict name checking, such as editing the registry or adding an SPN. However, I am not having any issues connecting to the server using CNAME aliases I have created, using either Windows or SQL authentication.

Is it still necessary to specifically disable strict name checking to avoid some unforeseen issues later on? Is the fact that I am already able to connect to this server using an alias due to a difference between SQL 2014 and earlier versions?

The server is running Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. Before it goes into production, it will become a node in an AlwaysOn failover cluster, so the CNAME records will actually be pointing at the cluster Virtual Network Name, not the server's host name, if this makes any difference?